# CAAnimation - User Input Disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation

I am trying to animate a button.  When I do so (using button.layer addAnimation) the button becomes disabled.  Is there any way to allow user interaction when animating?  I also tried wrapping everything in a block using animateWithDuration passing in the option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction, but it still doesn't work.

EDIT: It's odd.  If I click in the upper corner (where I placed my button) it fires off the event.  It's almost like the frame of the button does not follow the animation.

EDIT: What I ended up doing is create an event that fires every 0.1 seconds that sets the button.frame equal to the [[button.layer presentationLayer] frame]. That seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is create an event that fires every 0.1 seconds that sets the button.frame equal to the button.layer

Comment: the best solution is to change the position of the layer after you call the animation:
button.layer.position = endPosition;

Answer (score 1):

Use the following UIView method with UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in the UIViewAnimationOptions parameter:

+(void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion

Comment: That won't work.  The problem was the button's frame was not being animated.

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is to change the position of the layer after you call the animation:

```
[button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];

 button.layer.position = endPosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

To me the event firing seemed a bit *hacky*.
However your mentioning of the `[[button.layer presentationLayer] frame]` brought me onto the right track :-)

So by attaching a gesture recognizer to the superview of the moving view I can do the following detection:

```
CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

for (UIView* childView in self.view.subviews)
{
    CGRect frame = [[childView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, tapLocation))
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the button to zoom in. So I scale down the layer before I start the animation:

```
layer.transform = CATransform3DScale (layer.transform, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01);

// some animation code
```

After the animation I scaled it back.

```
// some animation code
CATransform3D endingScale = CATransform3DScale (layer.transform, 100, 100, 100);
// some animation code

[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform"];

layer.transform = endingScale;
```

Looks like if you directly assign it to the layer the frame will change. However using an animation won't change the frame.