# how to to make gesturerecognizer working in an animating UIImage view

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uianimation

i have 5 animating image in a image view and will like to allow user to tap on them base on the default ID and push it to another view. i tried to add in gesture tap but the imageview are not detecting.

can anybody give me some advise ?

EDIT: end up i did not use it, i set a UIButton instead.

thank you :)

viewDidLoad

```
self.defaultID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"7",@"9",@"11",@"27",@"6",nil];
self.defaultImageCaption = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ver",@"Green",@"Red",@"CF",@"Dwarf",nil];

//default image
imageViewTop.alpha = 1.0;
imageViewBottom.alpha = 0.0;
imageViewBottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,367)];
imageViewTop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,367)];

singleDefaultTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDefaultTap:)];
singleDefaultTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
imageViewTop.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageViewTop addGestureRecognizer:singleDefaultTap];
imageViewTop.tag = 2000;

UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,367)];
[topView addSubview:imageViewTop];
[self.view addSubview:imageViewTop];
[self.view addSubview:topView];
[self.view addSubview:imageViewBottom];

[self nextAnimation]
```

---

```
-(void)nextAnimation{

//picture loop
imageViewTop.image = imageViewBottom.image;
imageViewBottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:[imageArray count] - 1];

[imageArray insertObject:imageViewBottom.image atIndex:0];
[imageArray removeLastObject];
imageViewTop.alpha = 1.0;
imageViewBottom.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     imageViewTop.alpha = 0.0;
                     imageViewBottom.alpha = 1.0;
                     } 
                 completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                     [self nextAnimation:stringsize.width];
                 }
 ];
```

---

action

//show your alert...

```
NSLog(@"tapped");

flowerDetails = [[FlowerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlowerDetailViewController" bundle:Nil] ;
Fr *fr = nil;
```

//push to flower detail view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because that when animation is applying, the modification for any value of the sprite(UIImageView in your case) by animation is not applied to the sprite original, it is applied to its .layer.presentationLayer, the real one is still at its original place. In this case, you can try this: Put your gesture on the whole screen, when response comes from event, you check the touch point, make a hitTest to the presentationLayer, if yes then do what you want.

I usually use below code to do that.

```
- ( BOOL ) areYouThere: ( CGPoint ) point {
    return ( [ ( ( CALayer * )sprite.layer.presentationLayer ) hitTest: point ] != nil );
}
```

Get the touch point from a UITouch object when below method is invoked

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Answer (score 5):

I would add a transparent view on top of the image view and add a gesture recognizer to that.

Comment: i see how do i pass the value based on the transparent view ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Really late but I've been facing the same issue and I found what I think is a better solution:

Just use the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option like that:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{ 
                     imageViewTop.alpha = 0.0;
                     imageViewBottom.alpha = 1.0;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                     [self nextAnimation:stringsize.width];
                 }
];
```